# how to pass properties to another component via the onlick event of an element rendered by the map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

I am creating an application in `react` that takes output from a `mongodb` database. In one of the `Gallery` components, I have placed a `map` function that displays a list of items. I would like to add an `onClick` event to each element of the array, which would pass each property to the other component as state.
I have looked for hints in other posts, but none fit my case. I have also tried to solve it myself as far as my skills with `react` allow me.
What I would like is to pass the individual properties i.e.: `file.name` and `file.cover` to the other component.

Gallery Component:

```
function Gallery() {
  const [name, setName] = useState()
  const [cover, setCover] = useState()

  const video = [...]
  
  const seeDetails = () => {
    setName(???)
  }
  
return(
<section>
  <ul className='grid grid-cols-2'>
    {video.map((file) => (
      <li key={file.name} className='relative' onClick={seeDetails}>
        <div>
          <img
            src={file.cover}
            alt={file.name}
          />
        </div>
        <p>
          {file.name}
        </p>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</section>

<SecondComponent name={name} setName={setName} cover={cover} setCover={setCover} />
)}
```

SecondComponent:

```
const SecondComponent = ({ name, setName, cover, setCover }) => {
  return (
    <p>{name}</p>
    <img src={cover} alt={name} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seeDetails` function doesn't seem to have any provision to be able to access your `file` object. It be able to accept the `file` object as a parameter, which I can see from your code snip, contains everything you need to share with `SecondComponent`

Try:

```
const seeDetails = (file) => {
    setName(file.name);
    setCover(file.cover)
  }
```

and you will need it to be explicitly passed through the `onClick` prop as

```
<li key={file.name} className='relative' onClick={(event) => seeDetails(file)}>
```

Also, if it is feasible, instead of creating individual states for name, cover, xyz; would be good to have the `file` object itself maintained in the state.

Comment: Indeed, your solution works as I expected. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you give me an idea of what such a object would look like in the state ?

Comment: Something like const [file, setFile] = useState({name: 'init value', cover: 'init value',... })